# Fix elements to viewport top

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

This is kind of a weird predicament, because I ended up using flexbox to align menu items in my `sidenav` and `header`, as well as grid to display/allocate space for my `nav` and `header` components.

I've tried methods for making solely grid or flexbox based sidebars (or headers) be sticky but they don't work at all.

Here's an example of what I have:

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <nav>
        <div class="menu-item">Link</div>
    </nav>
    <div class="header"> Header Content Here </div>
    <main> Main Section. This should be able to scroll while Nav and 
           Header are sticking to the top
    </main>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.grid-container {
    grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
      "sidenav header"
      "sidenav main";
      box-shadow: 5px 10px !important;
  }

nav {
  grid-area: sidenav;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 12px 2px whitesmoke;
  background-color: white;
  display: none;
  z-index: 100;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: #f8f9ff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0px 16px;
}

main {
  grid-area: main;
  background-color: #f8f9ff;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining grid and flexbox properties like you are trying to do is the right thing - you need to add a bit more to make them work:

- add viewport height to your grid so that you can make your `header` and `sidebar` sticky.
- you can specify your `header` height using `grid-template-rows` (see snippet below)
- add `overflow-y: auto` to force only the `main` to overflow.

See demo below:

```css
body  {
  margin: 0;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh; /* Add total height of the grid */
  grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr; /* sets sidenav width */
  grid-template-rows: 75px 1fr; /* sets header height */
  grid-template-areas: "sidenav header" "sidenav main";
  box-shadow: 5px 10px !important;
}

nav {
  grid-area: sidenav;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 12px 2px whitesmoke;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 100;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: #f8f9ff;
  display: flex; /* flexbox to center items */
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0px 16px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

main {
  grid-area: main;
  background-color: #f8f9ff;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow-y: auto; /* add scrolling */
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <nav>
    <div class="menu-item">Link</div>
  </nav>
  <div class="header"> Header Content Here </div>
  <main> Main Section. This should be able to scroll while Nav and Header are sticking to the top<br/> Lorel ipsum some text here <br/> Lorel ipsum some text here <br/> Lorel ipsum some text here <br/> Lorel ipsum some text here <br/> Lorel ipsum some text here
    <br/> Lorel ipsum some text here <br/> Lorel ipsum some text here <br/> Lorel ipsum some text here <br/> Lorel ipsum some text here <br/> Lorel ipsum some text here <br/> Lorel ipsum some text here <br/> Lorel ipsum some text here <br/> Lorel ipsum
    some text here <br/> Lorel ipsum some text here <br/> Lorel ipsum some text here <br/> Lorel ipsum some text here <br/> Lorel ipsum some text here <br/> Lorel ipsum some text here <br/> Lorel ipsum some text here <br/> Lorel ipsum some text here <br/>    Lorel ipsum some text here <br/> Lorel ipsum some text here <br/> Lorel ipsum some text here <br/> Lorel ipsum some text here <br/> Lorel ipsum some text here <br/> Lorel ipsum some text here <br/> Lorel ipsum some text here <br/> Lorel ipsum some
    text here <br/> Lorel ipsum some text here <br/> Lorel ipsum some text here <br/>
  </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by adding `display: grid` to the container and removing `display: none` from the `nav` element. Then add `overflow: auto` to the `main` element to enable the scrolling function.

```css
.grid-container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "sidenav header"
                       "sidenav main";
}

nav {
  grid-area: sidenav;
  background-color: aqua;
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: orange;
}

main {
  grid-area: main;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #f8f9ff;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <nav>nav section</nav>
  <header>header section</header>
  <main>Main Section. This should be able to scroll while Nav and Header are sticking to the top<br><br>Main Section. This should be able to scroll while Nav and Header are sticking to the top<br><br>Main Section. This should be able to scroll while Nav and
    Header are sticking to the top<br><br>Main Section. This should be able to scroll while Nav and Header are sticking to the top<br><br>Main Section. This should be able to scroll while Nav and Header are sticking to the top<br><br>Main Section. This
    should be able to scroll while Nav and Header are sticking to the top<br><br>Main Section. This should be able to scroll while Nav and Header are sticking to the top<br><br>Main Section. This should be able to scroll while Nav and Header are sticking
    to the top<br><br>Main Section. This should be able to scroll while Nav and Header are sticking to the top<br>Main Section. This should be able to scroll while Nav and Header are sticking to the top<br><br>Main Section. This should be able to scroll
    while Nav and Header are sticking to the top<br><br>Main Section. This should be able to scroll while Nav and Header are sticking to the top<br><br>
  </main>
</div>
```